# Is it possible to annotate access to a user function in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In user defined procedures I can limit access with the allowed annotation like this:

```
    @Procedure(value = "search",allowed = "admin",mode = Mode.READ)
    public Stream<Node> search( @Name("label") String label)
    {
    ...
```

Is it possible to limit the access with annotation to a @UserFunction too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in the recent 3.2.x versions things have changed with regards to this. Everything is now being managed by neo4j.conf configuration settings. Check http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.security.procedures.roles for more details. User functions are covered too.

You'll notice that @Procedure do no longer have the "allowed" option.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom